# Making some info optional in regex

Tags: regex

I am writing regex for below pattern: **`sftp://user:password@host[:port]/path`**

I have written the following **`sftp://(.+):(.+)@(.+):(\d+)/(.*)`** which matches the pattern, where `group1` matches `user`, `group2` matches `password`, `group3` matches `host name` and `group4` matches `port number` and `group5` matches `path`

However, the port number can be optional parameter, I have tried the below regex where port group is followed by a **`?`**.

**`sftp://(.+):(.+)@(.+)(:(\d+))?\/(.*)`**

Here `group3` matches with **`host:port`** which is not what is expected.

How to make the regex where the port param is optional ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sftp://([^/@]+):([^/@]+)@([^/]+?)(?::(\d+))?/(.*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Pi02kq/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  sftp://                  'sftp://'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/@]+                   any character except: '/', '@' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/@]+                   any character except: '/', '@' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]+?                   any character except: '/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \5
```